# How to change the URL on redirect?

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I've got a site http://abcd.com that I want to redirect to http://efgh.com. This works.

But unfortunately I have to use an .htaccess provided by the domain hoster as the first URL has no actual web space behind it.

The problem is both .htaccess and meta-refresh within the second page don't actually update the URL as far as the browser is concerned (i.e. the location-bar still shows abcd.com even though we're on efgh.com). That is an issue because cookies from the page are therefore treated as third-party cookies.

**How do I change the URL the browser thinks it's on to solve the cookie issue?**

**EDIT:** Perhaps I wasn't clear enough:
The redirect itself **works**. The **content** is from **efgh.com**. But the **location bar** in the browser shows **abcd.com** which is important because it turns cookies from efgh.com into third-party cookies.

**EDIT2:** Aargh, after bashing my head against the wall for ages I only now realized the domain hoster boxed me into a hidden frameset. I can't believe I was this stupid and didn't realize it sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to send a 301 redirect for the old domain in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Notice the `R=301` on the last line - this will tell the browser that the move is permanent - the browser will then move on to another domain.

Comment: That doesn't work. The browser still shows abcd.com in the location bar and the cookies can't be set. Thanks for the reply, anyways. =)

Comment: @user2296153 What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome and IE, no difference

Comment: I just tested it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari - all three work correctly.  I don't have access to an IE.  Post your config **EXACTLY** as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `R' flag in your`RewriteRule` for external redirection (change the URL).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abcd\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://efgh.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Since you're using `R=301` here, make sure to test in a different browser.

Comment: The same as the other reply. It redirects just fine but the browser pretends it doesn't.

Comment: Make sure to test it in a different browser. Also please explain what you mean by `browser pretends it doesn't`?

Comment: See my explanation above, the location bar shows abcd.com. It's the same in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Do you want to keep URL in browser as `abcd.com` even after redirect to `efgh.com` ?